# Can a Oracle query done after a commit, return values prior to the commit when such commit is done with COMMIT_WRITE = NOWAIT?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle19c

I have a 3th party Java library that in a moment, gets a JDBC connection, starts a transaction, does several batch updates with `PreparedStatement.addBatch()`, executes the batch, commits the transaction and closes the connection. Almost immediately after (in the span of <10 milliseconds), the library gets another connection and queries one of the records affected by the update.

For the proper functioning of the library, that query should return the updated record. However, in some rare cases, I'm getting (using [P6Spy](https://github.com/p6spy/p6spy)) that the query is returning the record with its values before the update (and the library fails in some point forwards due to unexpected data).

I'm trying to understand why this would happen, and then I found that in my database (Oracle 19c) there is a parameter [COMMIT_WAIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/COMMIT_WAIT.html#GUID-40E51330-96D0-4B98-BBF3-6A45D970AAB1) that basically gives the possibility that a call to a commit doesn't block until the commit is finished, obtaining [an asynchronous commit](https://www.orafaq.com/node/93). So I used the `SHOW PARAMETERS` to see the value of that parameter and I found out that `COMMIT_WAIT` is set up to `NOWAIT` (also, `COMMIT_LOGGING` was set up to `BATCH`).

I began to speculate if what was happening was that the call to `commit()` just started the operation (without waiting for it to finish), and perhaps the next query occurred while the operation was still in progress, returning the value of the record before the transaction. (The isolation level for all connections is `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`)

**Can `COMMIT_WAIT` set up to `NOWAIT` cause that kind of scenario?** I read that the use of `NOWAIT` has a lot of risks associated with it, but mostly they refers to things like loss of durability if the database crashes.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the commit behavior should *not* affect database consistency and should *not* cause wrong results to be returned.

A little background - Oracle uses REDO for durability (recovering data after an error) and uses UNDO for consistency (making sure the correct results are always returned for any point-in-time). To improve performance, there are many tricks to reduce REDO and UNDO. But changing the commit behavior doesn't reduce the amount of logical REDO and UNDO, it only delays and optimizes the REDO physical writes.

Before a commit happens, and even before your statements return, the UNDO data used for consistency has been written to memory. Changing the commit behavior won't stop the changes from making their way to the UNDO tablespace.

Per the [Database Reference for COMMIT_WAIT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/COMMIT_WAIT.html#GUID-40E51330-96D0-4B98-BBF3-6A45D970AAB1), "Also, [the parameter] can violate the durability of ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) transactions if the database shuts down unexpectedly." Since the manual is already talking about the "D" in ACID, I assume it would also explicitly mention if the parameter affects the "C".

On the other hand, the above statements are all just theory. It's possible that there's some UNDO optimization bug that's causing the parameter to break something. But I think that would be extremely unlikely. Oracle goes out of its way to make sure that data is never lost or incorrect. (I know because even when I don't want REDO or UNDO it's hard to turn them off.)

Comment: Thanks for the information! I'm reading [On Transaction Isolation Levels](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/post/on-transaction-isolation-levels) and if I understand correctly, the UNDO data contains the data before the transaction, and allows for a external query (ie. outside the tx.). to not get those changes until they're committed, getting the pre-tx state instead. So, at which point in time external queries will start getting the data changed by the tx.? After the commit, I understand, but at which moment? When the commit request is sent? When the redo logs are written? Other?

Comment: With your commit settings, UNDO data will be finalized before the redo logs are written. (In fact, UNDO data is created while a DML statement is processing, and is read by other sessions immediately - that's how sessions know that a row is locked.) But I don't know the precise moment the commit happens. Perhaps you need to speak to someone who is an expert in Oracle internals, such as an Oracle Support engineer. But this would be one hell of a rare bug, and you'd have to build a very simple yet convincing test case, or they'll just assume the behavior is an application error.